DryIOC scanning assembly for registrations
The following CastleWindsor registration scans the executing assembly for all types that have the interface IInterceptor.
      IocContainer.Register(
            Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                .BasedOn<IInterceptor>()
                .WithService.Self()
                .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleSingleton()
            );

It registers in the IOC container as the interface that  matches the type name. For example.  It would find the following class and register it as an IAuditingStore.
public class AuditingStore : IAuditingStore, IInterceptor
{}

What is the equivalent registration in DryIOC?
